# Cannot update single property in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to update only single property of an entity but I cannot update it.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
public async Task ChangePassword(string User, string Password)
{
    using (var context = new abcContext())
    {
        var user = await context.Members.Where(c => c.UserName == User).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var member = context.Members.Find(user.PersonID);
        var coolBlog = new Member { PersonID = member.PersonID, 
                                    Password = member.Password };

        context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

        context.Members.Attach(member);
        context.Entry(member).Property(c => c.Password).OriginalValue = coolBlog.Password.ToString();
        context.Entry(member).Property(m => m.Password).IsModified = true;

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    };               
}
```

It is not updating password property in my database. Please guide me I have searched internet but couldn't find any appropriate solution.

Comment: Since you're already loading `member` from the context - there's absolutely no need to do a call to `context.Members.Attach(member);`. If you find the `member`, just update its properties and then call `.SaveChangesAsync()` on the context.

Comment: @marc_s thanks for the comment but i just want to update a single property not all properties. is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, as I said: retrieve the `member`, update those properties you want to update, call `.SaveChanges()` - Entity Framework will **only** update those properties that have been changed!

Comment: @marc_s i have tried your method but got error, can u please give me some code example please?

Comment: The response by @Fanda shows exactly how to do this - get the user, update a single property, save it back. Entity Framework will create an `UPDATE` statement from this that updates **only** the changed property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
public async Task ChangePassword(string User, string Password)
{
    using (var context = new abcContext())
    {
        var user = await context.Members.Where(c => c.UserName == User).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.Password = Password; // do some hashing on password to not store plain password
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i just want to update a single property not all properties. is there any way to do this? and does your code update only password property?